# For Tuncating table what statement is used?

Tags: asp.net

I have created one sp that tuncate table.Table name is dynamic.Here I used dynamic sql.Sp is working fine.I want to execute that sp from C#.net(from cs file).
I know executenonquery returns no of row affected.executenonquery is used for insert,update and delete command.Exectesclare is used for select which has only one cell.EceuteReader is used for selecting multiple record.What shall i use that tell  my tuncate table clause executed properly or not?

Comment: Why are you using the TRUNCATE command? It is not recommended in usual projects. I'd recommend to us DELETE  and then a DBCC ressed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ExecuteNonQuery` to truncate the table.

```
try
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
       connection.Open();
       string commandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE myTable";
       using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
       {
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          lblStatus.Text = "Table Deleted Successfully.";
       }
     }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   lblStatus.Text = "Table can not be deleted, Error " + ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: I agree that ExecuteNonQuery execute my sp.But it will return -1.If above sp execute properly,I have to do another processing.So it is necessary for me to check that table is truncated

Comment: @JuiTest:- I would recommend you to use `delete from table` instead of `truncate table tablename` as that would be more useful.

Comment: @JuiTest:- I have updated my answer. So if there is any exception while truncating you can catch it else it will show you as successful. Hope that helps

Comment: I have created 2 sp.My page logic is like this.In first sp,I am craeting table if not exist,if exist truncate it.In page I am doing some processing later on I adding/inserting data to that table.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the best way is to use [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
1. It returs the number of rows affected by the statement.
2. And if something doesn't work properly, you will get a nice SqlException which won't go by unnoticed.

```
try
{
    procedure.ExecuteNonQuery();
    nextStep.ExecuteWhatever();
}
catch(SqlException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Oh noes!");
}
```